Cumulative product for a random walk in QuestDB SQL
I have a dataset in QuestDB with daily returns for a stock, starting at $100. I want to calculate the cumulative product of the returns to simulate the stock's price path (random walk). The daily returns are stored in a table called daily_returns.
Here’s a sample of the relevant columns:



Date
Daily Return (%)




2024-09-05
2.00


2024-09-06
-1.00


2024-09-07
1.50


2024-09-08
-3.00


2024-09-09
2.50


2024-09-10
1.00


2024-09-11
-2.00


2024-09-12
1.50



I'm trying to calculate the cumulative product of (1 + return) for each day, starting from $100. This would be the expected output



Date
Daily Return (%)
Stock Price




2024-09-05
2.00
102.00


2024-09-06
-1.00
100.98


2024-09-07
1.50
102.49


2024-09-08
-3.00
99.42


2024-09-09
2.50
101.91


2024-09-10
1.00
102.93


2024-09-11
-2.00
100.87


2024-09-12
1.50
102.38



I know QuestDB doesn't have a direct cumulative product function, and I found this nice trick (maths to the rescue!) where you can use a window function and get the exponent of the sum of the logarithms for each day, and that would be the same as a cumulative product.
Problem is that QuestDB does not allow to use any functions on top of a Window Function result, so when I do:
 SELECT 
        date,
        return,
        exp(sum(ln(1 + return)) OVER (ORDER BY date)) AS StockPrice
    FROM daily_returns

I get an error "dangling literal".
Any workarounds here or cannot cumulative product can be calculated using QuestDB?

You want SUM to be the window function, not EXP, look more closely at your linked answer and you'll see the brackets are in slightly different places.  (Voting to close as this is caused by a typo.)

Thanks! Will edit. Still valid as in QuestDB you cannot use any other function on top of the result of a window function and the error I get is 'Dangling Literal', so we still need to do it in two steps. But very good catch!

Hey @MatBailie. I fixed the question as per your suggestion. I think it is relevant (We got this exact question at QuestDB's public slack and I thought it was nice so I wanted to put it here for larger reach)

Even if we cannot use exp on top of a window function, it doesn't mean we cannot still use a cumulative SUM on a CTE and then use exp for every row.
WITH ln_values AS (
    SELECT 
        date,
        return,
        SUM(ln(1 + return)) OVER (ORDER BY date) AS ln_value
    FROM daily_returns
)
SELECT 
    date,
    return,
    100 * exp(ln_value) AS "StockPrice"
FROM ln_values;

And this is the outcome

